# Using addExpression and GROUP_CONCAT gives null result

Tags: database, migrations

This has been bothering me for a few days now.

Using Migrate module, I am using a GROUP_CONCAT in an expression and the prepareRow always has a null value for the expression.

For example, heres how my query looks at the moment;

```
$query = Database::getConnection('default', 'custom_migrate')
         ->select('Articles', 'a')
         ->fields('a')
         ->condition('a.SiteID', 'site-id', 'LIKE');

// Join our tags. Use LIKE again.
$query->leftJoin('TagAssociation', 'ta', 'ta.InstanceId = a.id AND ta.Class LIKE :param', array(':param' => 'article'));
$query->leftJoin('Tag', 't', 'ta.TagId = t.id AND t.SiteId LIKE :param', array(':param' => 'site-id'));
$query->addExpression("GROUP_CONCAT(t.Tag)", 'customTags');

// Join our show data.
$query->leftJoin('ShowContent', 'sc', 'sc.ContentId = a.id AND sc.Type LIKE :param', array(':param' => 'article'));
$query->leftJoin('Shows', 's', 's.Id = sc.ShowId');
$query->addField('s', 'id', 'ShowId');

$query->groupBy('a.id');
```

Pretty simple stuff, but in both `prepare()` and `prepareRow()` I get a null value for `$row->customTags`. Even If I leave the alias off and use `$row->expression`. Null.

"Make the join a subquery!" I hear you say. Same thing.

Dumping the $query object (cast as string to see query) and putting my params in, I can query the db and get the values I expect.

```
SELECT a.*, s.id AS ShowId, GROUP_CONCAT(t.Tag) AS expression
  FROM Articles a
       LEFT OUTER JOIN TagAssociation ta ON ta.InstanceId = a.id AND ta.Class LIKE 'article'
       LEFT OUTER JOIN Tag t ON ta.TagId = t.id AND t.SiteId LIKE 'fiveaa'
       LEFT OUTER JOIN ShowContent sc ON sc.ContentId = a.id AND sc.Type LIKE 'article'
       LEFT OUTER JOIN Shows s ON s.Id = sc.ShowId
 WHERE (a.SiteID LIKE 'fiveaa')
 GROUP BY a.id
 LIMIT 20; // Added by me.
```

Yep, the expression column is populated with comma separated tags, as expected.

SO, somewhere between me creating this query and the prepareRow method, the value is being lost.

Now, before I dig into the module code I thought I'd get a sanity check from anybody that can to see if I'm doing something dumb that I've missed.

**Note** The field mapping for this field has been removed while I work out what is going on.

**UPDATE** Ok, so, the file sql.inc in the migrate module where it executes the query looks like this (around line 335);

```
migrate_instrument_start('MigrateSourceSQL execute');
$this->result = $this->query->execute();
migrate_instrument_stop('MigrateSourceSQL execute');
```

If I add some debug ...

```
var_dump($this->query->getExpressions());
var_dump((string)$this->query);
migrate_instrument_start('MigrateSourceSQL execute');
$this->result = $this->query->execute();

$row = $this->result->fetchAssoc();
var_dump($row);
```

I can see my expression ...

```
array(1) {
  ["contentTags"]=>
  array(3) {
    ["expression"]=>
    string(19) "GROUP_CONCAT(t.Tag)"
    ["alias"]=>
    string(11) "contentTags"
    ["arguments"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
  }
}
```

And I can see my query (as above) but ... null result on that col.

```
  ["contentTags"]=>
  NULL
```

**UPDATE 2**
So, if I change my leftJoins to joins, I get no results at all ... While running the query manually with joins returns rows.

**FINAL UPDATE**
I am now doing a separate query in the prepare method to get these values. I couldn't work out what was going on or the best course of action. I'll leave this open incase others have issues and post in here.

Comment: I use it here http://cgit.drupalcode.org/advagg/tree/advagg_bundler/advagg_bundler.module#n180

Comment: @mikeytown2 thanks but this is beyond the use of GROUP_CONCAT, this seems to be a legitimate bug somewhere.